# C# Datetime problem

Tags: c#

ı need first monday future week ?

how to make C#?

now date 09.jan.2009

ı need 15.jun.2009 monday

Comment: and I want first Sunday. [@oraclee, please add some details]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work too

```
DateTime monday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + 1).AddDays(7).Date
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get first Monday following a certain date, do this:

```
DateTime GetFirstMondaySince(DateTime afterWhen)
{
   int dayOfWeek = (int)someDate.DayOfWeek;
   int wantedDay = (int)DayOfWeek.Monday;
   return afterWhen.AddDays((wantedDay-dayOfWeek+7)%7);
}
```

For first monday of the year, use GetFirstMonday(DateTime(2009,1,1))

etc..

NOTE: untested code. Please understand and test carefully before using.

First Monday next week: `GetFirstMondaySince(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(2));`

Answer (score 1):

```
    public DateTime GetNextMonday()
    {

            DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;

            if dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
            {
                 dt.AddDays(7);
            }
            else
            {
               while (dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
               {
                dt = dt.AddDays(1);
               }
            }
            return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Loops should not be substitute for arithmetics.

Comment: What if `dt` is Monday? It will never loop and basically return `DateTime.Today`.